# why instantiate a class method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the idea behind creating a new instance of a method inside the `class << self` construct?
I understand methods are put under the `class << self` block to make them class methods but what does it mean to create a new instance of the method itself?

```
class foo
  class << self
     def bar(param)
       new.bar(some_param)
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can only create instances of classes and methods are not classes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - so is this creating a new instance of a class? why not just do foo1 = new.foo then.

Comment: First, class names are constants, so you want `class Foo`. Suppose `Foo.bar('cat')` is executed. When the line `new.bar('cat')` is executed `self #=> Foo`, so that's equivalent to `Foo.new.bar('cat')`. `Foo.new` is an instance of `Foo` so Ruby looks for an *instance* method `F#bar` (as distinct from the class method `Foo::bar`), but finds none and therefore raises an exception.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - sorry, i'm new to this. I'm little confused, so are you saying the line new.bar() raises an exception ?

Comment: Please edit to change `class foo` to `class Foo`. You will find that  `Foo.methods.include?(:bar) #=> true` (there's a class method `bar`) and `Foo.instance_methods.include?(:bar) #=> false` (there's not an instant method `bar`). `Foo.new` is an instance of `Foo` so it can only invoke instance methods. Since there's no instance method `bar`, `Foo.new.bar #=> NoMethodError (undefined method 'bar' for #<Foo:0x000058787cf803c0>)`.

Comment: The code you posted is not valid Ruby code (it raises a `SyntaxError` exception), so it is impossible to say what it means because it *doesn't mean anything*. It is invalid. You cannot execute it, therefore it means nothing.

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please see "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We must have runnable code, otherwise the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your trying to describe is a convenience method:

```
class FooService
  def initialize
    @bar= Bar.new
  end

  # this does the actual work
  def call
    results = @bar.do_some_work
    results.each do
       # ...
    end 
  end

  # this is just a convenient wrapper
  def self.call
    new.call
  end
end
```

This lets you call the `FooService.call` class method for instead of manually instantiating the class with `FooService.new.call`. It does not really look like that much from this simple example but its really useful for abstracting away object initialization in things like service objects or to combine initializer arguments with method arguments.

```
class ApiClient
  def initialize(api_key)
    @api_key = api_key
  end


  def get(path)
    # ...
  end

  def self.get(path, api_key: ENV['API_KEY'])
    new(api_key).call(path)
  end
end

ApiClient.get('foo')
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. in your ApiClient class example. new(api_key).call(path) , in this statement new(api_key) creates a new instance of the ApiClient class? what is the .call(path) do?

Comment: It actually calls the instance method. Without that it would just return the new instance of ApiClient so you would have to call `ApiClient.call(path).call(path)`.

Comment: In a class method `new` is equal to `self.new` and since self if the ApiClient class it equates to `ApiClient.new`.  In Ruby `.new` returns an instance of a class.

Comment: that's what I had guess for the new(api_key) that it initializes a new instance of the ApiClient class and passes the "api_key" parameter to it's initialize function. but I don't see .call method in this class , where is that defined, or is it a special method in ruby?

Comment: In this case it's just a normal method name.